# C# 2D array from user input

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am completely new to programming, but I was wondering how it would be possible to create a 2D array from user input??

Say the program is for adding soccer players statistics

```
Console.WriteLine("Please add the players name: ");
Playername = Console.Readline();
```

From here, how could I make `PlayerName` go into a 2D array?

Other variables and required data include goals scored, and games played.

As I said, I am a complete begginner, so any help is more than welcome!!

Comment: Can you give an example of the data input, and what you want it to look like in memory?

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested for-loops.

```
//For 25 players.
int Row = 5;
int Column = 5;

string PlayerData[column][row];

 for (int i=0;i<Column;i++)
 {
     for (int j=0;j<Row;j++)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Please add the players name: ");
        Playername = Console.Readline();
        PlayerData[i][j]=playername
        // Add more prompts and attributes here.
     }
 }
```

I recommend you get a beginner's book to programming.
If this solves your problem don't forget to mark the answer and up-vote other answers or questions that you help you. Welcome to SO.